Proving $\lim_{x\to 10} \ln(x - 3) \neq \infty$ by epsilon-delta
I am not good at those proofs, and I cannot find any resource because the part of limits is always reduced to the minimum, with few explanations.
$$\lim_{x\to 10} \ln(x - 3) \;=\; +\infty$$
This is clearly false.
$$\forall M > 0, \exists \delta_M > 0 : 0 < |x-x_0|< \delta \implies f(x) > M$$
I am not able to follow this definition to arrive a contradiction, which is what I want.
$f(x) > M$ implies $x > 1 + e^M$.
Now I cannot understand how to choose some $\delta$ to show that it's not true that for every $ M > 0$ I have $\ln(x-3) > M$.
How to reason? I don't want to use the negation of the definition.

Why do you refuse to use the "negation of the definition"?

@BrunoKrams Because I want to arrive to a contradiction using the direct definition.

To find a counter-example, you need to find one $M$ such that for every $\delta>0,$ there is an $x\in(10-\delta,10+\delta)$ such that $\log(x-7)<M.$

"Now I cannot understand how to choose some $\delta$ to show that it's not true that for every $ M > 0$ I have $\ln(x-3) > M$": you must not "choose some $\delta$", and what you must show is not that.

You want to prove that the assertion$$(\forall M>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in(3,\infty)):|x-10|<\delta\implies|\log(x-3)|>M$$is false. In other words, you want to prove that$$(\exists M>0)(\forall\delta>0)(\exists x\in(3,\infty)):|x-10|<\delta\wedge|\log(x-3)|\leqslant M.$$So, take $M=1+\log(7)$. Let $\delta$ be any number greater than $0$. Given $x>4$, you have\begin{align}|\log(x-3)|\leqslant M&\iff\log(x-3)\leqslant1+\log(7)\\&\iff\log\left(\frac{x-3}7\right)\leqslant1\\&\iff\frac{x-3}7\leqslant e\\&\iff x\leqslant3+7e.\end{align}So, it will be enough to take some $x\in(10,10+\delta)$ with $x\leqslant3+7e$, which is possible, since $3+7e>10$.

This was really enlinghtening. Thank you

I'm glad I could help.
